# Docker MySql automate configuration of `mysql.user` table (or Ansible)

Tags: mysql, docker, configuration

MySql is installed via docker and ansible scripts.

To be able to login to the container from the host, now I manually login to the container and run the sql statement:

```
$ docker exec -it bm_my_sql bash
bash-4.2# mysql -uroot -p
update mysql.user set host = '%' where user = 'root';
```

Then from the host I can login to the container as:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

The question is, how can I update `mysql.user.host` field for the root user via docker configuration or via ansible script.

Cannot find any config settings for this.

Comment: This is managed via env vars and an entrypoint script on the official mysql docker image. Here is the one for version 8: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh. You can find the corresponding env vars in the image doc: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: @Zeitounator, it was an issue for me to find `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` env variable. Carefully had a look again and found. Unfortunately it is only mentioned in the docs, without the description. User can only guess, what it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MySQL dockerhub image:

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
> dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
> data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
> by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

So you can just put a SQL script with that statement in a volume that maps to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` dir.

Comment: thank you. it is a more flexible, but for this issue also more complicated solution.